# looping curl and grep to query an API and process result all in one action

Tags: bash, loops, curl, grep

Initially I was having trouble piping a curl and grep command because I was getting the same exit code if the server was down as I was for if the pattern was not found and that wasn't good. Here are some examples of solutions I was given for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
if curl http://192.168.1.2/api/query | grep -q mypattern; then
  echo "Found pattern"
elif [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Server up"
else
  echo "Server down"
fi
```

Here is the other one:

```
if while ! curl http://192.168.1.2:8080/api/query; do sleep 1; done | 
    grep -q mypattern; then
    echo "success"
fi
```

Now I am stuck again and trying to adapt them. Right now it will retrieve the contents of the queue. If it can't reach the server, it keeps trying until is does reach it. It will then process the queue to find the pattern. But I need to confirm the server is reachable AND process the queue all in one action. If EITHER the server is unreachable or the pattern is found, keep trying until the server responds AND the pattern is not found in the queue. After that, then I will do whatever. I am having trouble trying to come up with an efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the standard output of the entire `while` loop (which includes the output of the `curl` command) to *another* loop that runs until it finds your pattern in its input:

```
while ! curl http://...; do
  # Write to standard error so that it isn't sent to grep
  echo "Server down, waiting one second" >&2
  sleep 1
done | 
  until grep -q mypattern; do
    echo "Waiting for pattern to match"
  done
```

Comment: It's not working. At the very end of this I added

    `echo "Queue pulled." >> /config/log.txt'
    if [ "$1" = "category1" ]; then
    echo "category is correct." >> /config/log.txt`

 The echos are for troubleshooting and the `if` starts the next part of the script. I also directed the "Waiting for pattern" to output to the same file. My output is:

Queue pulled.
category is correct.
Waiting for pattern to match
Waiting for pattern to match

Things seem to be out of order. It shouldn't be telling me the category is correct until after it successfully found the pattern.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your actual script is based on comments. You might be better off with another question detailing *exactly* what script you are running and what the output is.

Comment: My script is the one chepner just suggested and then I added the echos I mentioned because it isn't working.